# Вывод хранимой процедуры в DataGridView

Tags: sql, linq

Добрый день. В базе имеется хранимая процедура:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ОтчётПоУчащ_8
AS
SELECT Цифра_класса, Литера_класса,Фамилия_учащегося, Имя_учащегося, Тип_учёта, Дата_постановки, Причина_постановки,Дата_снятия
FROM Классы INNER JOIN (Учащиеся INNER JOIN Учёт ON Учащиеся.id_Учащегося = Учёт.id_Учащегося) ON Классы.id_Класса = Учащиеся.id_Класса
```

Пытаюсь вывести результат хранимой процедуры в `DataGridView`:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Connect.DB.ОтчётПоУчащ_8();
```

Ничего не выводит. 
Подскажите, в чем может быть дело, может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Слишком мало информации. Приведите больше данных.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю :1) Язык C#?2)СУБД MS SQL?3) Используется Entity Framework ?

Comment: Русское название объектов БД- это плохая практика. Вам самому удобно при набирании текста запроса скатать между 2 умя раскладками?